# UriBuilder points to localhost instead of domain name

Tags: c#, asp.net, uribuilder

My site has a public section that is accessed by http and a https part to requires logging in. When logging out of the site, it redirects to the http public index page.

Previously I had done this with stating the full url to point too. Recently I had to get rid of such things so the site can be run on numerous domains, for testing.

I tried using UriBuilder to convert https links to http link so that a website no longer has to use direct pointing to a specific url. This should allow the site to use any domain name. Right now it points to the computer name.

```
if (Request.IsSecureConnection)
{
    UriBuilder ub = new UriBuilder();
    ub.Path = "/html/index.html";
    ub.Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttp;
    ub.Port = -1; // use default port for scheme
    Response.Redirect(ub.Uri.ToString(), true);

    //An old direct link to the site
    //Response.Redirect("http://www.someaddress.com/html/index.html");
}
```

When the code is triggered remotely on the test server instead of pointing to the right domain it returns me to the address

```
http://localhost/html/index.html
```

Instead of

```
http://testserver/html/index.html
```

I have no idea why it is doing this instead of returning the address I am connecting to the server via.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify host than default host (`"localhost"`) will be used - see [`UriBuilder()` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0t38awd9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) article on MSDN.

Fix: specify host (probably based on incoming request's host).

```
 ub.Host = GetMeIncomingHost();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in the URI to which you are redirecting, you haven't specified an *authority* (host). Thus, your redirect sends a `302 Found` HTTP status and the response contains a `location:` header that looks like something like this:

```
location: /html/index.html
```

That is a *relative* URI, relative to the current URI from which the redirected request originated. That means it inherited the scheme and authority component of the requesting page (which, obviously, in your case, was an `http://localhost:xx/...`.

To fix this, seed your `UriBuilder` in its constructor with [`HttpContext.Current.Request.Url`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.url%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). That should about do it:

```
UriBuilder ub = new UriBuilder( HttpContext.Current.Request.Url );
ub.Path   = "/html/index.html";
Response.Redirect(ub.Uri.ToString(), true);
```